# How to delete connection in draw2d.js?

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

I want to delete  a connection between two objects in draw2d.js. I am trying to find direct method that delete a connection but i did not found it. So please tell me if any way or is there any method available that delete or disconnect connection.
Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `CommandStack` support:

```js
canvas.remove(connection);
```

With `CommandStack` Support (undo/redo):

```js
var cmd =  new draw2d.command.CommandDelete(connection);
canvas.getCommandStack().execute(cmd);
```

Comment: Thanks This works. But need to make one change please use correct spelling on "execute"

Answer (score 0):

```
 draw2d.ContextmenuConnection.prototype.getContextMenu = function() {    
     var menu = new draw2d.Menu();
     menu.appendMenuItem(new draw2d.MenuItem("Disconnect", null, function() {
         //draw2d.Connection.workflow.removeFigure(draw2d.Connection.prototype);
         var cmd =  new draw2d.CommandDelete(**draw2d.Connection**);
         draw2d.Connection.prototype.workflow.getCommandStack().excute(cmd);
     }));

 };
```

you must handover an object to the constructor of the CommandDelete and NOT **draw2d.Connection**

see below:

```
 draw2d.ContextmenuConnection.prototype.getContextMenu = function() {    
     var menu = new draw2d.Menu();
     var oThis = this;
     menu.appendMenuItem(new draw2d.MenuItem("Disconnect", null, function() {
         //draw2d.Connection.workflow.removeFigure(draw2d.Connection.prototype);
         var cmd =  new draw2d.CommandDelete(oThis);
         draw2d.Connection.prototype.workflow.getCommandStack().excute(cmd);
     }));

 };
```